# atmega328 raspberry pi 2 communication

Tags: serial, atmega328

I have an atmega328p (running on it's internal 8mhz clock) receiving data over rf. I need the data received to be communicated to the raspberry pi 2 using its gpio pins, I cannot use USB. I don't have the budget for a gertduino. Is there any way to do this directly? I only need to be able to receive serial output on the pi, no uploading sketches.

Answer (score 1):

Both the Arduino and the Raspberry PI have interfaces like SPI, I2C and UART. These interfaces will make it easy for you to communicate between the two. I suggest you search for UART unless you need a very high data throughput, then you need to go for SPI. But unless you want to send over a thousand messages per second UART will work just fine.

Comment: Just remember that if you power your uC with 5V you will need to level translate it, otherwise you can fry the raspberry and/or the atmega will not hear the rPI